# Error while installing perl-DBD-mysql

Tags: centos, yum

When I want to install perl-DBD-MySQL on my CentOS 6.3 system,
I get this error:

`yum install perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64`

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.013-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Using `--skip-broken`:

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.013-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 from base
```

What package should I install?

Comment: This issue is a bit old but as I had encountered the same kind of issue and landed on this page. So, I'd like to add an answer, which is there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756308/problems-installing-mariadb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you encounter the installation of a package that complains it "requires" something, you should try and remember to use this command to determine what RPM package provides this file. In your case the message:

```
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
```

is supposed to be a hint. Granted, it's a little weak, but with this info you can run the following command to determine the package that contains this `.so` library file:

```
$ yum provides "*libmysqlclient.so.16*"
```

which will give you the following:

```
mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 : The shared libraries required for MySQL clients
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Other       : libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
Filename    : /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
Filename    : /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16
```

**NOTE:** You'll likely get multiple hits, one for each version of this package that's in the yum repositories.

From this you now know which package provides the file, `mysql-libs`. So just do this to install it:

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-libs
```

This package looks to be part of the base installation and was available in the updates repo under CentOS 6.4.

```
$ repoquery --location mysql-libs
http://mirrors.advancedhosters.com/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.i686.rpm
http://mirrors.advancedhosters.com/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this message : `No package mysql-libs available.` for `sudo yum install mysql-libs`

Comment: @hpn - what's your version of CentOS? I'm on CentOS 6.4 and it's in the updates repo which is part of the base installation.

Comment: @hpn - run this command to see what repos you have `yum repolist`. `updates` should be in that list.

Comment: Yes. `updates` is included, but `repoquery --location mysql-libs` returns nothing

Comment: @hpn - If you're desperate you can download the rpm from the URL I've added to my answer and try a `yum localinstall --nogpgcheck ...`. I'd do that up to the point where it's asking for y/n to confirm, and say no.

Comment: @hpn - yes so it's likely not in the list of packages that are available for 6.3. Your choices are (1) update to 6.4, (2) manually try installing the 6.4 RPM that I provided link to or (3) install one of the official MySQL [packages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/linux-installation-rpm.html). If it's not a server I'd be inclined to just do the upgrade to 6.4. It should be painless.

Answer (score 0):

As from your question it is not clear, which version of `CentOS` you use and if it is `MySQL` or `MariaDB` packages for database you have, I will provide my solution, which works on `CentOS 7` for `MariaDB`.

I have installed `MariaDB` engine from https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=kisiek&distro=CentOS&distro_release=centos7-amd64--centos7&version=10.1 and my dependency problem has gone.

As for any other platform, where you might experience similiar problem, try to choose your OS from: https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=kisiek
It didn't require any additional work after installing `MariaDB` from their official repository.

But still, the question is not verbose enough to provide proper answer for your case - my answer may or may not be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem using the following command:

```
yum install perl-DBD-MySQL --enablerepo=*
```